# performance issue in Solr/Cassandra during TTL

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We are using Datastax for solr/cassandra. Currently our search response is under 200ms. but every five minutes the response goes to around 10 seconds. 
After debugging we nailed down the cause to TTL. The ttl thread runs every 5 minutes and thats when we see the performance hit. But we are not able to figure out what is that TTL thread is doing to block the reads ?
Datastax Enterprise version:4.8

Anyone has any ideas please share .
Thanks

Comment: More likely you just need to autowarm your caches. I've never heard of ttl having this kind of impact. You would need very strong evidence for this extraordinary claim.

Comment: We are auto warming the cache,we tested with both 60% and 90%(but the same issue). I am thinking may be very high value of this might cause this. May be while autowamring the new searcher creates some sort of lock on old searcher to get the keys, which blocks the old searcher for serving read requests for that minor lock period. Just a theory for now

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like TTL triggers an index update, after which a new searcher will be opened. If Solr does not have auto-warming set, the first search(es) against a newly opened searcher can be slow.

If you can locate solrconfig.xml, you can check if auto-warming is enabled. From the DataStax documentation (https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226369-Solr-Configuration-Best-Practices-and-Troubleshooting-Tips) it seems to be off by default. I am sure they have experience that shows that this is a proper default, but try enabling it to see if it helps your specific setup.

Comment: We are auto warming the cache,But our autowarmcount is 90%. I am thinking may be very high value of this might cause this. May be while autowamring the new searcher creates some sort of lock on old searcher to get the keys, which blocks the old searcher for serving read requests for that minor lock period. Just a theory for now